# Simulate the commads of a given bash script

Tags: bash

i'd like to know if there's an utility to print only what the executed commands will be from a bash script, without actually executing it. A term for this would be a "dry-run".

I know I can "echo" every command i want, but that's not tenable for every script.

Regards.

Comment: Seems like there ought to be a bash one-liner to just print the file as-is, minus the comments, but I can't think of what it would be.  Is that what you're looking for?  Or do you want to follow some conditional logic and only print the path that it actually takes?

Comment: one could specify which lines are dry-run. In some cases some scripts have variables that take values only at run time, maybe a version of bash that doesn't actually execute the commands just evaluates variables and prints the command that would be executed.

Comment: @Rinzwind That's why I asked.  I think the general case of that is impossible, as later conditions can be affected by the execution of earlier commands.  A limited subset may be possible, so if we're going to go that route, we need some clarification on what that subset is.  For example, `No conditionals allowed, except for what is already determined when the script starts.`  Even then, it may need a custom software project for this one application.

Comment: Another possibility is to write a wrapper script that looks at its first argument to determine whether to execute its remaining arguments or print them, then does that and returns the result.  Or instead of the first argument, it could look for a file, or whatever you want to do.  Then modify all of the other scripts to use that wrapper instead of the commands directly.  You'll want to figure out what to return when it's printing, as that may affect how the "master" script runs, and there may be other problems too.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no "dry run" version of bash, or any other shell interpreter.  Such a thing would quickly become useless with anything that has conditions based on the results of earlier commands.  You pretty much have to run those commands for real to make the later branches work as intended, and then you're not "dry running" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no "dry run" version of bash, or any other shell interpreter.  Such a thing would quickly become useless with anything that has conditions based on the results of earlier commands.  You pretty much have to run those commands for real to make the later branches work as intended, and then you're not "dry running" anymore.  By the time all of those problems are fixed, it's practically the real thing again.

But depending on how your scripts are structured, you might be able to make something that works "well enough":

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "execute" ]    # replace with your favorite keyword
then
    CMD="$1"
    shift
    exit $CMD "$@"          # "$@" is "all arguments", minus what was shifted away
fi
echo "$@"                   # will also print the simulated return value,
exit $1                     #   but that might be okay
```

I haven't actually tried to run that, so there may be errors, but you get the idea.  (my native language is C, not bash)  Modify all of the other scripts to use this instead of the commands directly.  Or instead of the first argument, you might look for a file, or whatever you want to do.  Keep in mind that if you're printing instead of executing, the simulated return value or exit code could be important to keep the proper flow of the "master" script.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather impossible: "state changes" are impossible to simulate. It would require for every command in Linux (including external commands) to be aware of this. Or if the scope can be limited to your script: it would require all the commands you use for that script to be rewritten to be aware of it.

---

```
bash -n {script}
```

will do a syntax check of a `bash` script. Same with  `zsh` and `ksh`. If the file is correct nothing is printed, if it is not it will echo the linenumber where the syntax error is.

---

```
bash -x script
```

will print every line *before executing*

---

If you want to test a script you need to recreate the situation: create a backup, execute the script, restore the backup. Or use a 2nd system or a partition to do what your script needs to do.